# Get site owners from list of Sharepoint sites

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have list of Sharepoint urls around 600 sites and need site owner names for those sharepoint sites.please let me know is there any powershell script for to displayowner and url in thisharepoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

All sites in the farm:

`Get-SPSite -Limit ALL | select Url, Owner*, SecondaryContact`

single site:

`Get-SPSite https://some.site.collection.url | select Url, Owner*, SecondaryContact`

Comment: I updated my answer. 
More info about Get-SPSite: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-spsite

Comment: I have 400 sites and need to give as input and get the site owners and url using powershell